# How to "cut off the tail" of a series

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of 10 terms with their scores. The first x tend to be much more important than the rest. So I want to find x.

For example, [plotting this list](http://www.chartgo.com/get.do?id=60ed576003) shows a plateau after third term. Hence we keep the first 3 terms. Even intuitively, keeping first 3 terms seems appropriate.

```
    badge                                   =>    7.00709342956543
    unlocked                                =>    7.00709342956543
    foursquare                              =>   5.830315748850505
    https                                   =>   5.001254081726074
    you've unlocked                         =>   4.954763253529866
    50xxxxxx badge                          =>   4.954763253529866
    all badges                              =>   4.954763253529866
    unlocked far                            =>   4.954763253529866
    badges                                  =>   4.954763253529866
    just unlocked                           =>   4.954763253529866
```

But how to generate this cutoff **programmatically**? I prefer stuff available in standard libraries.

Comment: So, I guess one approach would be to abs() the difference of the terms, order the resulting list of differences in descending order. Set your "threshold" difference (say 2.5), and the ignore any difference < 2.5 from the list.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your "terms" will be sorted in a descending order as shown in the example you have provided. I would simply establish a delta (say 0.5) which represents a difference small enough to be ignorable.

I would then traverse through the collection of terms adding them a resultant collection and as soon as I see a term within "delta" of my previously seen term, I'll end my iteration and potentially remove the last seen term from my resultant collection as well.

Does that make sense?

Something that looks like this:

```
delta = 0.5
result = []
for term in termMapSortedKeys:
     if (previousTermValue - delta >= termMap[term]):
          break
     else:
          result.append(term)
          previousTermValue = termMap[term]
del result[-1]
return result
```

Comment: If you want more terms, I'd suggest making that the delta between this item and the one `k` down the list.  That way you can not stop at a tie, but still stop once the list has stopped growing.

Comment: @btilly: You are absolutely correct! Maybe, it makes more sense to traverse the list in the opposite direction (ascending order of term values). As soon as you encounter a term with value > previousTermValue + delta, you start recording the items. I guess the biggest disadvantage with that approach is you would end up reading a whole bunch of junk before getting to the meat.

Answer (score 0):

For a std-lib friendly way, you can use itertools.tee to do comparisons between the items in the list and return the deltas as in iterator. Then grab the data within your tolerance using itertools.takewhile.

```
import itertools, sys

def delta(data):
    '''yield the original data and the delta to the next item as tuple'''
    a, b = itertools.tee(data)
    yeild (next(b, None), sys.maxint) # assume the first item always passes :)
    for n in itertools.izip(a, b):
        yield n[1], abs(n[1] - n[0])


# example...
data = [0,1,2,3,4,6,6.125,6.25,6.375,6,6,6.25,5,6,6, 4.5, 2.5, 7]
data.sort()       
print data
# [0, 1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.125, 6.25, 6.25, 6.375, 7]


filter_fn = lambda x: x[1] > .05 # tolerance goes here...
trimmed = [item[0] for item in itertools.takewhile(filter_fn , delta(data))]
print trimmed 
# [0, 1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5, 5, 6]
```